# compile command executed inside script gives error, executed outside is fine...might be gcc

Tags: macos, bash, script, gcc

I have a script called buildgcc.sh with the following contents.

```
mymac$more buildgcc.sh 
g++ -Wno-write-strings A.cpp B.cpp B.cpp c.cpp D.cpp E.cpp F.cpp artgdg.cpp G.cpp H.cpp I.cpp J.cpp K.cpp L.cpp M.cpp N.cpp O.cpp P.cpp
```

When I run the script I get an error:

```
mymac$./buildgcc.sh
No such file or directory+-4.2: P.cpp
```

But when I copy/paste the contents of the script into the command line:

```
mymac$g++ -Wno-write-strings A.cpp B.cpp B.cpp c.cpp D.cpp E.cpp F.cpp artgdg.cpp G.cpp H.cpp I.cpp J.cpp K.cpp L.cpp M.cpp N.cpp O.cpp P.cpp
mymac$
```

It works fine... anyone give me a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
#!/bin/sh
```

at the start of your script. Otherwise the system has no idea what the heck that .sh file is.

Alternately, you could do

```
sh buildgcc.sh
```

at the command line.